# How to pass only one store type to a component (when the store is a union type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, type-safety

I'm using Typescript with React/Redux.

A site visitor can be in one of two states, `LoggedIn` or `LoggedOut`. I've structured my state accordingly:

```
interface LoggedIn {
    token: string,
    user: Data.User
}

interface LoggedOut {
    isLoading: boolean,
    lastAttempFailed: boolean
}

type Store = LoggedIn | LoggedOut
```

Coming from Haskell & Elm, this feels natural. In theory, it would be impossible for implementations to acccess `undefined` or `null` data, because they'd only be able to access state relevant to the components (i.e. once the user is logged in, a component cannot access `LoggedOut.isLoading`).

How can I integrate this with `mapStateToProps`? I have a `Provider` component supplying my store. I want certain components to only accept a `LoggedIn` or `LoggedOut` instance - not the entire store.

Ideally, this would be type-checked and passed down by a parent component, e.g.:

```
class PrivateRouteComponent extends React.Component<OwnProps & ConnectedState, any> {
    render() {
        const { store, component, ...props } = this.props;
        const Component = component;
        switch (store.type) {
            case "LOGGED_IN":
                return <Route render={() => <Component store={store as Store.LoggedIn} {...props}/>}/>;
            case "LOGGED_OUT":
                return <Redirect to="/login"/>;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is hacky and it feels un-idiomatic to pass the store through props. (Aside: this also makes it very hard to use route params in `react-router`).

Is there a good, typesafe solution to this problem? Cheers

Comment: Can you explain what you feel is hacky about your solution? Is it that you are casting `store` to a `LoggedIn`? That shouldn't occur if you set up the types for `LoggedIn` and `LoggedOut` correctly. Also, you say that you don't want to pass in the whole store -- but the whole store is the entire object for LoggedIn/LoggedOut, so that's kind of unavoidable. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Basically, in Elm/Haskell I can guarantee that my main state will be in a certain configuration, which removes the need for a lot of "if state is x then y, else z". I'm trying to implement the same guarantees in Typescript, to avoid constant switch statements.

Comment: TypeScript can guarantee that the store is *valid*, but that doesn't get rid of any conditionals in your code since you're gonna want to handle them differently based on their state.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get around. In Elm, I can pattern-match on the union type and render different routes accordingly. The specific types (e.g. `LoggedIn` or `LoggedOut`) are then passed to the component, not the whole union. How can I do this neatly in Typescript, without passing the store through props (which a lot of people discourage)?. Perhaps I need something to do with `Context`? I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

The following should type check correctly. Unfortunately, I believe that `react-redux`'s `connect` utility's type definitions doesn't properly support union types being mapped in `mapStateToProps`.

This still has conditional rendering, but I don't see how that's any different from using pattern matching in Elm.

```
/** represents the store when logged out */
interface LoggedOutStore {
  type: 'LOGGED_OUT';
  login: LoggedOut;
}

/** represents the store when logged in */
interface LoggedInStore {
  type: 'LOGGED_IN';
  login: LoggedIn;
}

type LogState = LoggedInStore | LoggedOutStore; // the part of the store with login state
type AppState = LogState & OtherStateFields; // the actual redux store

// dummy components w/ typing
const LoggedInComponent = ({ login }: { login: LoggedIn }) => <></>;
const LoggedOutComponent = ({ logout }: { logout: LoggedOut }) => <></>;

function LogStateComponent(props: LogState) {
  switch (props.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN':
      return <LoggedInComponent login={props.login} />;
    case 'LOGGED_OUT':
      return <LoggedOutComponent logout={props.login} />;
  }
}
// Pick<LogState, never> === {}
type ConnectedLogStateComponentType = ConnectedComponentClass<
  typeof LogStateComponent,
  Pick<LogState, never>>;

// this should work in theory; but unfortunately, it needs casting
const ConnectedLogStateComponent = connect((s: AppState): object => s)
  (LogStateComponent) as any as ConnectedLogStateComponentType;

const initState: AppState = {
  login: { isLoading: false, lastAttemptFailed: false },
  type: 'LOGGED_OUT',
};

export const App = () => <Provider store={createStore((s = initState) => s)}>
  <ConnectedLogStateComponent />
</Provider>;
```